# Using getElementsByname to fill in form fields with IE object but value not getting set?

Tags: powershell

The browser navigates to the url, but the searchbox wont get populated.
The html element has a name but not an id.
Can one set the value using the element returned from this method (getElementsByName) ?

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("https://www.google.com")
while($ie.Busy) { 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 
}
$ie.visible=$true
$doc=$ie.Document
$doc.getElementsByName("q")="visual studio"
```

error:

> char:1
>   + ($doc.getElementsByName("q") | Select-Object -First 1).value="visual  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular/SPA are a pain to access with COM. Sometimes you have to go at it "the other way around". First get all elements by Tag name (input) and then filter by name:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("https://www.google.com")
while($ie.Busy) { 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 
}
$ie.visible=$true
$doc=$ie.Document
$inputTags = $doc.getElementsByTagName("input")
$SearchBox = ($inputTags |Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'q'})
$SearchBox.value = "Visual Studio"
```

Or, if you are specifically doing a Google search, call the URL directly:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=Visual+Studio
```

Replacing spaces with `+` plus signs:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("https://www.google.com/search?q=Visual+Studio")
```